# How to tag an enumerated list?

Tags: enumerate, tags

I want to tag the mark value of the question right to it as follows

[image]
Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsthm,multicol,enumerate}

\begin{document} 
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \parbox{350pt}{A palindrome is a string whose reversal is identical to the string. How many bit strings of length $n$ are palindromes?}[1 pt]
  \item \parbox{350pt}{How many elements are in $A_1\cup A_2$ if there are $12$ elements in $A_1$, $18$ elements in $A_2$, and}[1pt each]
  \begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset$
    \item $|A_1\cap A_2|=2$
    \item $|A_1\cap A_2|=7$
    \item $A_1\subseteq A_2$
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}
  \item \parbox{300pt}{Find the value of $r$ if $\displaystyle \frac{P(10,r-1)}{P(11,r-2)}=\frac{30}{11}$.}[2 pts]
  \item \parbox{350pt}{Prove that the number of bit strings of length $n$ is the same as the number of subsets of the set of integers $\{1,2,\ldots n\}$.}[3 pts]
\end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you should have a look at exam document classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are dedicated classes and packages to design problem sheets and exams (c.f. https://ctan.org/topic/exam), but as a quick hack you could place the points into the margin:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsthm,multicol,enumerate,marginnote}

\begin{document} 
\begin{enumerate}
  \item A palindrome is a string whose reversal is identical to the string. How many bit strings of length $n$ are palindromes?\marginnote{[1 pt]}
  \item How many elements are in $A_1\cup A_2$ if there are $12$ elements in $A_1$, $18$ elements in $A_2$, and\marginnote{[1pt each]}[2.7\baselineskip]%
  \begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset$
    \item $|A_1\cap A_2|=2$
    \item $|A_1\cap A_2|=7$
    \item $A_1\subseteq A_2$
  \end{enumerate}    
  \end{multicols}
  \item Find the value of $r$ if $\displaystyle \frac{P(10,r-1)}{P(11,r-2)}=\frac{30}{11}$.\marginnote{[2 pts]}
  \item Prove that the number of bit strings of length $n$ is the same as the number of subsets of the set of integers $\{1,2,\ldots n\}$.\marginnote{[3 pts]}
\end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

[image]